# Identifying duplicate entries in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have this column in Google sheets with 11 digits of code that is supposed to be a unique per row. The first 3 digits are the department location, and the last 8 digit is the batch number and it has to be unique.
 sample code:
`G0420220001` and `K0020220002`
I want to make sure that the last 8 digits are unique per row.
In Conditional Formatting, without the first 3 digits, I can use this custom formula
  `=countif(b:b,b:b)>1`
to highlight duplicates, and the `20220002` entry in row 1 will be highlighted if I input another `20220002` in a different row, but  `K0020220002` and `G0420220002`, which will appear to be unique at each other will not be highlighted.
I want that these two codes to be highlighted since the last 8 digits of both entries are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

It seems to me that this formula will do the job:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(RIGHT($A$1:$A,8)*($A$1:$A<>""),RIGHT(A1,8))) > 1
```

[image: Conditional Formatting]